# Create repeatable custom form fields in web2py?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, dry, web2py

I want to create twitter bootstrap compliant form.  According to the [docs for Twitter Bootstrap v2.2.2](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.2.2/docs/base-css.html#forms) (the version included with web2py) the html should look like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

I'm currently using `SQLFORM` which outputs html that doesn't really fit with this (even using `formstyle='divs'`).  Besides I want my html output to be clean without web2py artifacts such as `class="w2p_fl"`.  So my thought is to use a custom form.  However in doing this there would be a lot of repeated code.  That is, the following would basically need to be repeated for each field.

```
{{=form.custom.begin}}
<div class="control-group">
    {{=LABEL(form.custom.label['myfield'], _class='control-label',
        _for='mytable_myfield')}}
    <div class="controls">{{=form.custom.widget.myfield}}</div>
</div>
...
{{=form.custom.end}}
```

So how can I repeat the above unit of code so I could replace it with something like {{=bootstrap_field(db.mytable.myfield)}} or some other way to adhere to DRY?

What is the web2py way to do this? Create a view function? Pass a function in the dictionary returned by the controller? Create my own html helper? Create my own widget? Another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap 2, you can just do:

```
form = SQLFORM(..., formstyle='bootstrap')
```

For Bootstrap 3 (or any other custom formstyle you'd like to create), the `formstyle` argument can be a function (or other callable) that produces the form DOM. The function will be passed the form and a `fields` object, which is a list of tuples, with each tuple containing a CSS id, label, input element, and (possibly empty) comment/help text. To get an idea of what such a function should look like, check out [the one used for Bootstrap 2 forms](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/sqlhtml.py#L756).

Comment: Perfect!  Strange the `bootstrap` formstyle is nowhere in the documentation that I can find.  Also I saw that formstyle could be a callable in the documentation: `formstyle can also be a function that takes (record_id, field_label, field_widget, field_comment) as attributes and returns a TR() object.` But since it said `TR` and I didn't want a table I figured it couldn't do what I wanted.

Comment: Everything in my response is undocumented. The text you cited from the book is out of date -- that will still work, but you can now pass in a callable that generates the entire form DOM, not just individual `TR` objects (the framework code will inspect your function to determine whether it is of the legacy type or the new type based on how many arguments it takes -- if it takes 4 arguments, it assumes it's a legacy function).

Comment: Also I'd still be interested in the more literal answer to my question of how to handle a repeatable code unit (other than the formstyle function) if you have an answer for that to edit in.

Comment: If you want repeatable code to generate a form DOM, then something like the formstyle function would be the way to go (even if you don't actually use it with the `formstyle` argument, you'd still want a function along those lines to programmatically build up the form).

Comment: The key element that I'm not sure if I'm communicating clearly is if I just want to generate a repeatable *portion* of the DOM rather than the entire thing.  I'm guessing your answer would still be the same.  So I guess the idea is to define such function in my controller and then pass it to my view via `return dict(business=business, mycustomfunction=mycustomfunction)`? And then call the function from my view such as `{{=mycustomfunction(form, 'fieldname')}}`?

Comment: I would either define the function in a model file so it's available everywhere, or put it in a module and import it. You might also consider calling it in the controller and just pass the final form DOM to the view. If you just need to tweak the existing form DOM, you can use the [server-side DOM](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Server-side-DOM-and-parsing) functionality. Another option might be to create a special view template, include it in the view, and make sure the data it needs are returned from the controller.

Comment: If you need more help, ask on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py).